# Firebase Auth problems with data fetching after signing up and opening ProfileView

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, fetch

I'm having several problems which in my opinion can be connected with some asynchronocity between my firebase account creating model and fetching data once the account has already been created in order to display them in some view.

The first problem is that right after registering, my account is created in firebase auth service and then data given by user in sign-up form are sent to firestore to be stored there. If user's signing up process completes with success he is redirected to the main screen where the ProfileViewModel starts it's work. In that ViewModel all data from firestore (search parameter across all users data stored there is current sessionStore user's id) is being fetched and Profile model is created which is used in ProfileView to display profile's data like firstName or username. Unfortunately, this is not the way it works. After the user registers, he is redirected to the main page and when he switch to Profile tab, nil error appears in spite of data fetch process being executed (it is executed in the init of ProfileViewModel). What's more interesting when I restart the app after the error, everything works fine when fetching data is concerned. I discovered that right after registering I get the following error message in console output:
`The operation couldn’t be completed. (Fit_Vein.DatabaseError error 0.)`

The second problems is connected with TextFields. During login or registration processes I can input text on every text field without any problems. However when ProfileViewModel object loads and all the views connected to it, the click on any text field (e.g. on password change form or new workout creation, which is in any case not connected to ProfileView or ProfileViewModel, results in ProfileView nil error while displaying firstName or username. Just like tapping on any textField would mean erasing Profile model from the ViewModel.

Sorry for long descriptions of my problems but I wanted to show You the full image as good as I can.

The parts of my code that might be useful (tried to trim code to most important parts):

ProfileViewModel:

```
@MainActor
class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var sessionStore: SessionStore?
    @Published var profile: Profile?

    init() {
        Task {
            try await fetchData()
        }
    }

    func setup(sessionStore: SessionStore) {
        self.sessionStore = sessionStore
    }
    
    func fetchData() async throws {
        if sessionStore != nil {
            if sessionStore!.currentUser != nil {
                print("Fetching Data")
                Task {
                    let (firstname, username, birthDate, age, country, language, gender, email, profilePictureURL) = try await self.firestoreManager.fetchDataForProfileViewModel(userID: sessionStore!.currentUser!.uid)
                    
                    self.profile = Profile(id: sessionStore!.currentUser!.uid, firstName: firstname, username: username, birthDate: birthDate, age: age, country: country, language: language, gender: gender, email: email, profilePictureURL: profilePictureURL)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ProfileView:

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject private var sessionStore: SessionStore
    var body: some View {
        Text(profileViewModel.profile!.firstName)
        Text(profileViewModel.profile!.username)
    }
}
```

LoggedUserView (the first view that appears after user registers successfully):

```
struct LoggedUserView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var sessionStore: SessionStore
    @ObservedObject private var profileViewModel = ProfileViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
            TabView {
                ProfileView(profileViewModel: profileViewModel)
                    .environmentObject(sessionStore)
            }
            .onAppear {
                self.profileViewModel.setup(sessionStore: sessionStore)
            }
    }
}
```

Firestore data fetching implementation:

```
func fetchDataForProfileViewModel(userID: String) async throws -> (String, String, Date, Int, String, String, String, String, String?) {
        let document = try await self.db.collection("users").document(userID).getDocument()
        
        let firstName = document.get("firstName") as? String ?? ""
        let username = document.get("username") as? String ?? ""
        let birthDate = document.get("birthDate") as? Date ?? Date()
        let age = document.get("age") as? Int ?? 0
        let country = document.get("country") as? String ?? ""
        let language = document.get("language") as? String ?? ""
        let gender = document.get("gender") as? String ?? ""
        let email = document.get("email") as? String ?? ""
        let profilePictureURL = document.get("profilePictureURL") as? String ?? nil
        
        return (firstName, username, birthDate, age, country, language, gender, email, profilePictureURL)
    }
```

Comment: In `ProfileViewModel`, you call `fetchData` in `init`. But, you use `profileViewModel.profile!` in your `View`. That will guarantee a crash until `fetchData` has completed and you have your data. Are you familiar with optional binding (`if let`) to avoid doing force unwrapping? Any time you have `!` in your code to force unwrap you risk a crash -- it's generally a bad practice in most cases.

Comment: can you refer to this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6u3AnOKZd0 Is it helpful?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav, thanks for the video. My Firestore data fetching implementation was a little bit different, maybe this is the case. Will try to use the one from the video tomorrow. What's more, I will add fetchData method when the first view after registration appears. Also, I updated the post with the implementation of Firestore data fetching that I have had up to this moment.

Comment: @jnpdx I'm familiar with secure optional check methods however with example from the post I wanted to show you the problem which would not be the case if I had implemented guard let or if let. I have already done that and had indefinite ProgressView of which I mentioned in my previous post. My current problem is that data fetch do not work right after uses successfully registers.

Comment: I discovered that right after registering I get the following error message: `The operation couldn’t be completed. (Fit_Vein.DatabaseError error 0.)`

Comment: @DivyaniYadav, unfortunately the video you linked did not help :(

Comment: @Vader20FF no one here knows what `Fit_Vein` is or what threw the error. Did you use the debugger to trace back where it's getting thrown?

Comment: @Vader20FF introduce debugging and output what is contained in each function variable so we can try fathom what is being processed, and which call is being errored.